# Как пере навесить событие jQuery?

Tags: jquery, события

Как пере навесить событие,то есть есть метод:

```
      $('.rooms_hotel_img_wc').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/admin/hotels/upload_images',
            start: function(e, data) {
                    $(this).hide().after("<img id='ajax-loader-large' width='30px' src='/img/admin/ajax-loader.gif'>");
            },
            complete: function() {
                    $('#ajax-loader-large').remove();
                    $(this).show();
            },
            done: function(e, data) {
                 alert('text');
            }
    });
```

но проблема что класса `.rooms_hotel_img_wc` на странице нет кнопка с таким классом создается на странице по другому событию.

как то можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот смотрите: происходит то другое событие, создается кнопка, тогда и навешивайте обработчик на `.rooms_hotel_img_wc`.

Другой способ:

```
/**
 * если курсор попадает на элемент, то выполняем след. операции:
 */
$('.rooms_hotel_img_wc').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    /**
     * проверяем, ставили ли мы на этот элемент обработчик.
     */
    if($this.data('fileupload') == undefined) {
        /**
         * ставим атрибут и вызываем плагин.
         */
        $this.data('fileupload', true).fileupload({
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: можно но не выход , как то можно по другому

Comment: @ukroficer ну хотелось бы сначала услышать, почему этот способ не подходит? Еще один способ-то есть.

Comment: потому что код будет громоздким..

Comment: вызов одной функции  громоздко ?

Comment: вроде да..

Comment: @ukroficer другой способ еще более громоздкий, но зато событие будет навешиваться на все выбранные селекторы.

Comment: любой другой способ будет более громоздким, и у вас не событие навешивается, а вызывается плагин - немного другая ситуация.

Comment: к чему вообще вы наверное ошиблись вопросом, прочитайте внимательно вопрос?

Comment: (***немного мата***) fileupload это плагин, это не обработчик события, события в jquery вешаются так: 

 * `$(selector).event(handler);` где event это встроенный обработчик событий(либо плагин, который обрабатывает кастомные события), а handler это функция с аргументом e (объект события). 
 * $(selector).on('event',handler) где event - одно из событий включая кастомные. 

в вашем коде я не вижу ни того ни другого. 

если элемента нет, то как вы собираетесь применить к нему плагин ?

Comment: btw, существует плагин, который следит за появлением в DOM элементов, но он весьма тормозной, https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

Answer (score 0):

Это очень громоздко так как при создание поля там есть кнопка загрузки и текстовое поле и еще придется делать так

```
     $('textarea.texteditor').ckeditor({
            extraPlugins : 'gmap',
            toolbar: [
    ['Source','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
    ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
    ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField'],
    '/',
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
    ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Hhs','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],
    '/',
    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],
    ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About','-','gmap']
    ],
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Images',
                    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&currentFolder=%2F&NewFolderName=MyFolder',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=%2F&NewFolderName=MyFolder1?',
                    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'

    });
```

что такое  init_file_upload()

Вопрос   eicto вы вообще хоть не много понимаете о чем я спрашиваю.

Comment: обновил свой ответ.

Comment: слов нет, я вообще предлагал вам сделать просто в конце init_file_upload(); как раз после этого вызова, а вообще чего-бы не расширить ckeditor, там наверняка есть возможность

Comment: читайте доки/туториалы по [ckeditor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin)

Comment: не одно решение не подходит ...

Comment: Да оберните же вы наконец-то код в вашем ответе в функцию и вызывайте функцию при создании кнопки.

Comment: можете показать как не могу понять...

Comment: @ukroficer ну, эм, 

    function func_name() {
        // your code
    }

И потом просто вызываете её:

    func_name();

А вообще да, сначала следует мануал прочитать.

Comment: Так действительно можно,но не ужели нельзя сделать через триггер?

Comment: @ukroficer как вам объяснить то, вы навешиваете на выбранные селекторы (элементы) плагин, а не событие. Плагин никак не вызвать через триггер. Это обычная функция с доп. функционалом.

Comment: [`(>_<)`](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSLSvHhfJiqek9Nf-q4qgmayZQ3Oc61xYKWdy_sKXwLaixPR9ikKA)